# Mimicking iPhone user agent in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, user-agent

I'm tinkering with a phpbb mod which adds a skin for mobile phones, and to work on it in my computer I want to mimic an iphone. In Firefox I manage to do this using the "user agent switcher" extension which comes with built-in "iphone" feature:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/

However, in Chrome (which I prefer) I cannot make this happen. I downloaded what seemed to be the relevant extension:

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/aafciojnlamllgpkpdkbamkfgbofhgcj?hl=he

It doesn't come with a built-in iPhone mode, so I added the following user agent:

> "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543 Safari/419.3"

However, this seems to have absolutely no effect - the pages load normally and not in the mobile skin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change chrome user agent by running it from command line:

chrome.exe --user-agent="User Agent String"

check out [This Page](http://chromesavant.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-view-legacy-websites-with-chrome.html) for more information

Comment: Your link is broken, I believe it should now point to : http://chromesavant.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-view-legacy-websites-with-chrome.html

Answer (score 27):

With the latest release in the Chrome Dev Channel (version 18) you can browse to developer tool settings and change the user agent string directly without needing any plugins or command line options.

First download Chrome from the developer channel, restart it, CTRL+SHIFT+I and click settings on bottom right. You should now be able to select the UA string.

[image: Chrome Developer Channel User Agent String]

Comment: This is no longer just in the Dev channel. My regular Chrome (version 23) has this, plus some extra spoofing features like "device metrics" and "emulate touch". Note that this is all in the "Overrides" tab now, of the Chrome developer tool settings.

Answer (score 2):

[The User-Agent Switcher for Chrome](http://spoofer-extension.appspot.com/) works nicely, I just tested it out.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the portable version of chrome and created a custom shortcut to it to always have a mobile browser.

F:_SOE\Apps\GoogleChromePortable\GoogleChromePortable.exe --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543 Safari/419.3"

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  I added a shortcut to my start menu and updated the target box with the new user agent string.  I check about: in the browser and it confirms the new user agent is set, however, it doesn't render the site in its mobile version.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is now the [Ultimate User Agent Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ljfpjnehmoiabkefmnjegmpdddgcdnpo) in the Chrome Webstore. It's awesome!

Answer (score -1):

I don't think chrome can do that but using one of the proxy out there you would be able to do it like [privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/)

Comment: Since I had access to the source code I simply made a clone where the iPhone skin loads automatically. It's a workaround, but probably the most easy way to get rid of the problem...